# How do I split one array into two arrays in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an array for example:

`var coordinatesOut: [Double] = [1.0,2.0];`

How would I split the array so that I get:

`var coordinatesOut1: [Double] = [1.0];`

`var coordinatesOut2: [Double] = [2.0];`

Comment: Not sure if the split command works for arrays. You should try it.

Comment: You should describe the problem more precisely. Does the input array always have 2 elements? What result do you expect if the input array has zero, one or more elements?

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm new to this, someone has already answered my question. I will bear this in mind for next time. Thank you.

Comment: You're really funny. You ask the wrong question and accept the wrong answer.

Comment: How do you know it's the wrong answer?  Given the question, any answer below is possibly correct, and a few more besides `coordinatesOut.map { return [ $0 ] }` for example :)

Comment: Ehrm. His first (unedited) answer returned a `Double`, not a `[Double]` as requested. So it turned out that this wrong answer was the correct one to the wrong question. I think that is funny,

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

```
let a = ["a","b","c","d"]
let part1 = [a[0...1]]
let part2 = [a[2...3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var coordinatesOut1 = [Double]() 
var coordinatesOut2 = [Double]()

coordinatesOut1.append(coordinatesOut[0]);
coordinatesOut2.append(coordinatesOut[1]);
```

Comment: That does not return an array but Doubles.

Comment: Right now, but `var coordinatesOut1 = [coordinatesOut[0]]` would have been sufficient.

Comment: It turns out I do not need an array. Thank you